# How do I renew my apple developer membership from one membership type to another?

Tags: apple-id, development, developer-program

I'm trying to renew my Apple paid developer membership but I keep being forwarded to a page to renew the membership for individuals but I'm going for the enterprise membership this time round.

Can I do this without creating a new Apple ID?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what renew means? Here [are some](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51610/) previous [related questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156333/) you'll want to [differentiate your situation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154962/) from the [ground already covered](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15467/). Specifically, what's the issue with creating a new Apple ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the info from [Apple Dev Page](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.php):

> **If I am enrolled as an individual, can I change to a company membership?**
>
> Yes. To convert your iOS Developer Program membership from an individual to a company, please contact us. You can make this change only if you are the founder/co-founder of the company. As part of the conversion process, you may be asked to submit business documents to verify your company's identity.

There's a link to contact page in the link I provided.

Comment: But let's say my membership has already run out (which it has). Can't I just register as if I was a new person, without emailing support?

Comment: In order to do this You need new AppleID. If You want to have Your old AppleID You have to contact Apple.

Comment: It's highly unlikely you can resuscitate an expired personal account and then have it become an enterprise account. You'll want to talk this through with your business sales contact (or establish that relationship) if the idea of spending another $100 to just get your personal account reactivated is out of the question. I'd do that now then either have that refunded  or reimbursed once you have paid access to developer support and the enterprise account set up.

Comment: In the end I've decided the easiest thing to do was just create a dedicated email from the businesses domain name and create a new apple id with that, then register for the enterprise apple developer account.

Comment: @LondonGuy yup - I'd be lost without something like 1Password to keep track of which AppleID are for which company and VPP and DEP and developer etc....